# How can I replace a Link To that has a parameter with a history.push with a parameter within a table cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have the following code and wanted to know if it was possible to replace this `Link To` with a `history.push`, that has the following parameter as well, i.e.:

```
<TableCell style={{width: '10%'}}>
   <Link
      to={`/run-id/${item.run_id}`}
      style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', color: 'black' }}
    >             
      {item.run_id}
    </Link>
</TableCell>
```

Pls note that `item` is coming from a `items.map(item =>`

If possible, would appreciate some help on how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you want to replace with `Link to` parameter? Why do you want use `history.push`?

Comment: @Danial - wanted to see if possible and want to be able to push to a new page as this is within a nested route. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you don't use history because you just want a link. history.push would be more appropriate if you want to change the route programmatically (& not based on the client clicking an element)
but still, if you are curious, you can pass the history.push to TableCell's onClick function like this:

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"

const history = useHistory()

<TableCell style={{width: '10%'}} onClick={() => history.push(`/run-id/${item.run_id}`)}>      
    {item.run_id}
</TableCell>
```